# Getting an error ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Tags: sql, oracle

Im trying to insert data into an existing table but i getting an error. the table was defined as follows.

ITEM_NUM         CHAR(4)

DESCRIPTION     CHAR(30)

ON_HAND         NUMBER(4,0)

CATEGORY        CHAR(3)

PRICE          NUMBER(6,2)

here is the SQL that is presenting the error

```
INSERT INTO NONGAME
    VALUES ("CD33", "Wood Block Set (48 piece)",36,"TOY",89.49),
               ("DL51", "Classic Railway Set",  12, "TOY", 107.95),
               ("DR67","Giant Star Brain Teaser",24,"PZL",31.95),
               ("FD11", "Rocking Horse",8,"TOY",124.95),
               ("FH24","Puzzle Gift Set",65,"PZL",38.95),
               ("KD34","Pentominoes Brain Teaser",60,"PZL",14.95),
               ("MT03","Zauberkasten Brain Teaser",45,"PZL",45.79),
               ("NL89", "Wood Block Set (62 piece)",32,"TOY",119.75),
               ("TW35","Fire Engine",30,"TOY",118.95);
```

Comment: ummm... aren't you missing the `insert into` part?

Comment: there is an INSERT INTO NONGAME

Comment: That last edit was much appreciated

Comment: had to correct the code that part didn't copy for some reason

Comment: Oracle does not support multi-row `inserts`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your syntax to use `INSERT ALL` and replace the double quotes with single.

```
INSERT ALL
   INTO NONGAME (ITEM_NUM, DESCRIPTION, ON_HAND, CATEGORY, PRICE) VALUES ('CD33', 'Wood Block Set (48 piece)',36,'TOY',89.49)
   INTO NONGAME (ITEM_NUM, DESCRIPTION, ON_HAND, CATEGORY, PRICE) VALUES  ('DL51', 'Classic Railway Set',  12, 'TOY', 107.95)
   -- ADD AS MENU RECORDS AS YOU WANT HERE
SELECT 1 FROM DUAL;
```

The `SELECT 1 FROM DUAL` is required as `INSERT ALL` requires a SELECT sub-query and this gives a single row of dummy data.

> **INSERT ALL** gives performance improvements over individual insert statements so if you are inserting many records like this definitely use this syntax rather than inserting one at a time, see [Oracle Insert All](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/questions/insert_rows.php)

Regarding your comment:

> " i get ORA-00984: column not allowed here"

Because in SQL double quote marks are used for database object names: literals need single quote marks. (Code sample corrected to reflect this fact.)

Comment: thus far non of he sugestions have worked. i have tride simplifying it down to one colume  INSERT INTO NONGAME 
VALUES ("CD33", "Wood Block Set (48 piece)",36,"TOY",89.49); and i get ORA-00984: column not allowed here

Comment: Try one record again but this time explicitly state the table columns, e.g. INTO NONGAME (ITEM_NUM, DESCRIPTION, ON_HAND, CATEGORY, PRICE)

Comment: Problem resolved. I changed the double quotes to single quotes and it works fine. thank you all for your input though.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle supports single quotes and not double. Try this:

```
INSERT INTO NONGAME
    VALUES ('CD33', 'Wood Block Set (48 piece)',36,'TOY',89.49),
               ('DL51', 'Classic Railway Set',  12, 'TOY', 107.95),
               ('DR67','Giant Star Brain Teaser',24,'PZL',31.95),
               ('FD11', 'Rocking Horse',8,'TOY',124.95),
               ('FH24','Puzzle Gift Set',65,'PZL',38.95),
               ('KD34','Pentominoes Brain Teaser',60,'PZL',14.95),
               ('MT03','Zauberkasten Brain Teaser',45,'PZL',45.79),
               ('NL89', 'Wood Block Set (62 piece)',32,'TOY',119.75),
               ('TW35','Fire Engine',30,'TOY',118.95);
```

Comment: while that is true, Oracle does not support multiple rows with the `values` clause.

Comment: So what's the best way to do this with single quotes?